# Fullcalendar: Remove past events in listMonth?

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am trying to get past events to be removed from the list or to add a class to them so I can remove them with css.

**Code Using**

```
        $(function() {
            $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                defaultView: 'listMonth',

                googleCalendarApiKey: 'asdasdasdasdasd',
                events: {
                    googleCalendarId: 'asdasdasdasd@group.calendar.google.com'
                }
            });
        });
```

Seeing that today is Oct 20th, the calendar events from the from the 17th (image below and marked in red) should be removed.  So that the next upcoming event is always at the top.

[image: Fullcalendar Images]

Is this even posable with Fullcalendar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found this code that seems to do the job.   In case anyone else it looking.

```
eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
var eventEnd = moment(event.end);
var NOW = moment();
if (eventEnd.diff(NOW, 'seconds') <= 0) {
    return false;
}},
```

Found here: 
https://github.com/fullcalendar/fullcalendar/issues/3340